# What is the use of jquery.mobile.structure-1.0.css in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, rhomobile

I have a question. When i am creating an application in rhomobile jquery.mobile.structure-1.0.css present inside /public/jqmobile. My question
1) What is the use of jquery.mobile.structure-1.0.css
2) jquery.mobile.structure-1.0.css was not included anywhere (in layout.erb) the application. Then why jquery.mobile.structure-1.0.css is present. I  try to find the use of jquery.mobile.structure-1.0.css but not getting good result. Any one can explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I seperate the structure css out so I can make changes to my themes without causing any major issues to the new theme.css architecture.  Makes it a bit easier to make upgrades as new versions come out.   Though it is a little tricky to verify that there are no new additions to the themes.   I wouldn't use overrides on the base themes a,b,c,d, - I find it's better to build your own themes using those as bases, e,f,g, etc...

Answer (score 7):

The structure CSS is used to make a completely custom theme, where you do not want to rely on any of the default themes that come with jQuery Mobile. It's a very basic bare bones stylesheet. You can use it in place of the main jQuery Mobile stylesheet, then you create your own stylesheet to override and customize.